# argument type mismatch exception while marshelling the java object

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jaxb

I am converting a java object into xml string with the help of jaxb context marshelling technique.When i try and run the program as main class.it converts it into xml string but when i call the method from different class in project.it throws argument mismatch exception.
I am using tomcat 7 and jdk 6 and running the code in eclipse.
Please find marshelling snippet as below.

```
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Test.class);

                 m = context.createMarshaller();

                m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

sw = new StringWriter();

                m.marshal(request, sw);
```

Please guide on why its failing when i m running it into a project.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below way to marshal the Java object and use the XML writer to make xml format.

```
   JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Test.class);

   Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();

            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

   NamespaceFilter outFilter = new NamespaceFilter(null, false);
   ByteArrayOutputStream baOPStram = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

   //Use XML writer to create the xml file.
   XMLWriter writer = new XMLWriter(baOPStram);

   outFilter.setContentHandler(writer);

   m.marshal(**YourJavaObject**, outFilter);

   message = new String(baOPStram.toByteArray());
```

if you wish to save the xml file to somewhere , please give the reference of the output file.

```
   OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("xyz.xml");
   m.marshal(**YourJavaObject**, outFilter);
```

also set the below property before

```
   m.setProperty(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
```